# Store typing for Nextjs and Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

really couldn't find any good example for Nextjs and Redux with Typescript. Thought it'll be easy to port my create-react-app application to Nextjs feels like I was wrong already went through all possible example from nextjs example repo but couldn't find the best one that finally works.

this is the error

```
Property 'store' does not exist on type 'Readonly<AppInitialProps & { Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}>; router: Router; }> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2339)
```

here is my custom app

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import {initStore} from '../redux/store'




export default withRedux(initStore)(class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({Component, ctx}) {
        let pageProps = {}

        if(Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ctx})
        }
        return {pageProps}
    }

    render() {
        const {Component, pageProps, store} = this.props
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component {...pageProps}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel so stupid, finally got it fixed

```
import { Store } from 'redux'

interface Props {
  store: Store;
}
```